# Android: Updating int ever second

Tags: android, time, seconds

I am creating a text file with data related to my App's game.

I want to show the score at **each second** in the game.

How can I ensure that my int for seconds is updated, starting at zero

**Example of output wanted:**

```
Seconds      Score
0            3
1            9
2            16
3            20
.....etc
```

**Current output (seconds always 0):**

```
Seconds      Score
0            3
0            9
0            16
0            20
.....etc
```

**Current code:**

```
int seconds=0;

                //creating header in the txt file Note: Blanked out as it is generating every second
                writeToFileEEGPower(order("Seconds")+order("highAlpha")+order("lowAlpha")+order("highBeta")+order("LowBeta")+
                        order("lowGamma")+order("midGamma")+order("Delta")+order("Theta")+ "\n");

                //creating the string to be written to file
                String line = order(seconds+"")+order(eegPower.highAlpha+"")+order(eegPower.lowAlpha+"")+order(eegPower.highBeta+"")+
                        order(eegPower.lowBeta+"")+order(eegPower.midGamma+"")+order(eegPower.delta+"")+order(eegPower.theta+"")+ "\n";

                //write the string to file
                writeToFileEEGPower(line);
                seconds++;
```

Comment: use handler with 1000ms to call your function to update score and write your file

Comment: Can you please give a code example of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should rather use a sqlite table for this. [Greendao](http://greendao-orm.com/)
is a good tool for managing those tables. You can save the information every second to a table. When the game is finished, you have a full list of the score for each second of the game. 
In your code example the "second" variable is set to 0 each time before you write a new line. I think that is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using [TimerTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html) or [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) with postDelayed() method can do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a handler to update your text file every second:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private android.os.Handler mHandler = new android.os.Handler();
    private Runnable textFileLogger;
    private int seconds = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

        //Create header for text file
        writeToFileEEGPower(order("Seconds") + order("highAlpha") + order("lowAlpha") + order("highBeta") + order("LowBeta") +
                order("lowGamma") + order("midGamma") + order("Delta") + order("Theta") + "\n");

        textFileLogger = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                seconds++;
                String line = order(seconds + "") + order(eegPower.highAlpha + "") + order(eegPower.lowAlpha + "") + order(eegPower.highBeta + "") +
                        order(eegPower.lowBeta + "") + order(eegPower.midGamma + "") + order(eegPower.delta + "") + order(eegPower.theta + "") + "\n";
                //write the string to file
                writeToFileEEGPower(line);
                //Repeats the logging after 1 second
                mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            }
        };

        //Starts the logging after 1 second
        mHandler.postDelayed(textFileLogger, 1000);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        //To stop the logging:
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(textFileLogger);
    }
}
```

Comment: Im not sure exactly how to implement this, can you show me an example for my exact code please

Comment: It is not updating the seconds as I would like

Comment: What does it do with the seconds? It should count them up like 1,2,3, ... If it stays at 0 it's some kind of side effect from other program procedures.

Comment: Yes the seconds just stay at zero?

Comment: Must be some kind of side effect from your other code. The above code does not set seconds to zero.